# How to avoid animating movement when handling widgets out of view?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I currently have a listview which contain some widgets that I collapse when they leave the viewport, but this causes everything below to move upwards which becomes a really strange experience for the user.

Is there a way to have the widgets collapse without moving below when the collapse happens outside the viewport?

I use collapsible and visibility_detector to handle the collapse and the check for whether the widget is in view or not.